# Android Live Wallpaper - not showing background image?

Tags: android, wallpaper

I started implementation of android live wallpaper, following the examples and tutorials found on the internet, and I can't include png background as wallpaper. Also checked with similar problems here, and still can't make it work.

This is the code:

```
public class LiveWallpaper extends WallpaperService {

    /* IDs of recurces needed for animations*/
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new WallpaperEngine();
    }

    class WallpaperEngine extends Engine {
    public final Runnable mDrawWallpaper = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            drawWallpaper();
         }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        setTouchEventsEnabled(false);
        loadImagesIntoMemory(R.drawable.wallpaper);
        holder = getSurfaceHolder();

    }

    void drawWallpaperContent(Canvas c, int resourceId){
        Bitmap decodeResoure = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources(), resourceId);
        c.drawBitmap(decodeResoure, 0, 0, null);
    }

    void drawWallpaper(){
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas c = null;
            c = holder.lockCanvas();

        if(c!=null){
            c.save();
            drawWallpaperContent(c, R.drawable.wallpaper);
                    c.restore();
        }
        }

        private void loadImagesIntoMemory(int resourceId){
        Resources res = getResources();
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawWallpaper);           
        }
    }
}
```

Bitmap is stored in drawable folder, and the version of android sdk is 2.2.
After launching the live wallpaper, I only get 'Loading Wallpaper' without showing the wallpaper image.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

Thank you.
Dj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your draw

' Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);'

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);
```

you can pass null in paint parameter. m using this and its working

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar problem, `c.drawColor(0xff000000);` before drawing the bitmap was the solution for me.